# How can I speed up the numpy operations?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, parallel-processing, joblib

I am currently having a dataframe as shown below:

[image]

This dataframe has 1 million rows. I would like to perform the following operation:

Say for row 0, b is 6. 
I would like to create another column, c.

The c for row 0 is computed as the mean of a row (i.e. 8 rows in above image), where b is in range from 6-3 to 6+3 (here 3 is the fixed number for all rows).

Currently I have performed this operation by converting column a and column b to numpy arrays and then looping. Below I have attached the code:

```
index = range(0,1000000)
columns = ['A','B']
data = np.array([np.random.randint(10, size=1000000),np.random.randint(10, size=1000000)]).T
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=index, columns=columns)

values_b = df.B.values
values_a = df.A.values
sum_array = []
program_starts = time.time()
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
    value_index = [values_b[i] - 3,values_b[i] + 3]
    sum_array.append(np.sum(values_a[value_index]))

time_now = time.time()
print('time taken ',time_now- program_starts)
```

This code is taking around 8 seconds to run.

How can I make this run faster? I tried to parallelize the task by splitting  the array in 0.1 million rows and then calling this for loop in parallel for each 0.1 million array. But it takes even more time. Please, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `values_a[values_b - 3] + values_a[values_b + 3]`?

Comment: What does this mean. Can you explain @Divakar. Will this reduce time or you are asking something?

Comment: Go through NumPy indexing docs - https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by _"The c for row 0 is computed as the mean of a row (i.e. 8 rows in above image), where b is in range from 6-3 to 6+3 (here 3 is the fixed number for all rows)."_? Do you mean that `c[0]` is the mean of the 7 values `a[6-3], a[6-2], ..., a[6+3]`?

Comment: In the image you will see that for row 0. The c value will be mean of all rows where b's values is from 3 to 9. That is we will only find mean of those values of b which are b/w 3 and 9 (both included). In above image you will see all rows satisfy this condition.